# How to get all sheet names in another sheet (automatic update when add new sheetnames)

Tags: excel

I have an excel file with a MAIN sheet, and then multiple sheets. I need to show all the names of the multiple sheets, on my MAIN sheet like this;
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: When do you need it available? When having it active/when opening the workbook/immediately?

Comment: With `Excel Formula` you would need `Excel 4.0` Macro or else use `VBA` or `Power Query`. That said with `Excel 4.0` Macro enter this formula in Name Manager defined as `SHEETNAMES` --> `=REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")` and in front end of excel use `=INDEX(SHEETNAMES, ROWS(A$1:A1))` or for `SHEETNAMES` can use `=TEXTAFTER(GET.WORKBOOK(1),"]")` or inplace of `INDEX()` can use `=TOCOL(SHEETNAMES)`

Comment: where should I write this code? im new to excel

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I believe ROWS(A$1:A1) returns only current sheet name. Though =INDEX(SHEETNAMES, 0) would return a list of all sheets. Also it doesn't update until formula is "reentered". Partial and not the best workaround would be to stack in with some sort of volatile formula to update it when change is made on any other cell

Comment: @Hellihansen Formulas -> Define name. In "Name:" input SHEETNAMEs and in refers to add =REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")

Comment: @user11222393 you need to try that in a workbook to see for your reference, prior asking because without testing i have not commented. **[Look_Here](https://imgur.com/gallery/trpUpca)**

Comment: is get.workbook an excel function? is just that im trying to find it in my native language

Comment: You are not doing any research, all these posts are duplicates, you wont be able to do it with inbuilt functions, you need Excel 4.0 Macro. Here you can read **[more](https://exceloffthegrid.com/using-excel-4-macro-functions/)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya my bad. It works. I didn't drag down formula. This was why I got only 1 sheet name! Anyway =INDEX(SHEETNAMES, 0) spills all names at once.

Comment: I have done the sheetnames and the replace code. I then put my =INDEX(SHEETNAMES, ROWS(A$1:A1)) in the first cell under project, but i comes with and error?

Comment: You got answer for this in another question. Use semicolon instead of comma as separator.

Comment: Get the sheet name using CELL("filename",A1). Just need to use mid().

Comment: @user11222393 it does not work =INDEX(SHEETNAMES; ROWS(A$1:A1))
what does A$1 mean?

Comment: @SolarMike Doesn't that only return the filename of the formula containing the cell?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld includes the sheet name it is on. So mid() can be used to extract the name... See my edit to my answer.

Comment: @SolarMike So if he wanted a list of all sheet names that updated automatically, he'd have to use a template that included that formula on every sheet he added, wouldn't he?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld which is why my answer includes :*On each sheet there is in cell B1 the following:*"

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, it will work as long as the sheet names have `Sheet1` `Sheet2` etc but if the sheet names are random and different, it wont. Btw method is nicely explained.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes i know, but if the sheets are "Month1", "Month2" or a similar structure then it may be sufficient. If not I think there is in the vba that all sheets are "sheet1" , "sheet2" as base names even if they have been renamed...

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, yes I agree with your point that is why voted up. Even i was thinking the way Ron Sir has commented, but you have used `INDIRECT()` which made it possible some way. That is intelligent solution.

Comment: =INDEX(SHEETNAMES; ROWS(A$1:A1))  This does not work for me? should I change the A$1 to something else?

Comment: @Hellihansen did you define the name "sheetnames" as explained?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya indirect is so I can use the row number instead of an increment to increase the sheet number.

Comment: @SolarMike Sir ,correct agree

Comment: Relax? I need help and im asking politely. I dont have any expericence

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple method, but based on each sheet being named as per your example "sheetXX":

[image]

On each sheet there is in cell B1 the following:

```
CELL("filename",A1)
```

You can put this somewhere else or hide it, format it white etc etc

So, using mid() to get just the sheet name:

```
MID(INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()&"!B$1"),FIND("]",INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()&"!B$1"),1)+1,20)
```

Comment: Sir since only the sheet names are required, can you add `TEXTAFTER(your_formula,"]")` before your formula to get only the ones which is required otherwise it shows the full file path of your desktop

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya that is why I have shown the version with mid() to get just the name - did not use textafter() as that is not common to many versions of Excel and the OP does not make it clear which version is being used, so I built that to be more widely available.  Textafter(), Textbefore(), split() etc ARE very useful though :)

Comment: Ah okay understood!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I like your style, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA:

- On the worksheet where you wish to have the results
  _ Right click on the worksheet tab at the bottom

  - Select `View Code`
  - Paste the code below into the window that opens
- The list will update whenever you select that worksheet

  - *Note that when you add or remove a worksheet, that sheet will become active, and the change will be reflected in your list when you re-select the sheet that shows the list.*
- Can add routines to sort the list, if you want, and/or exclude the sheetname of the included list; or omit the code-names (which are really only useful in VBA)

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim V() As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    
With ThisWorkbook
    ReDim V(0 To .Worksheets.Count, 1 To 2)
    V(0, 1) = "Sheet Name"
    V(0, 2) = "Code Name"
    I = 0
    For Each WS In .Worksheets
        I = I + 1
        V(I, 1) = WS.Name
        V(I, 2) = WS.CodeName
    Next WS
End With

With Cells(1, 1).Resize(rowsize:=UBound(V, 1) + 1, columnsize:=UBound(V, 2))
    .EntireColumn.ClearContents
    .Value = V
    
'Can omit the next line
'The Style name might be different if your Excel is not English
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
    
End Sub
```